# Python: Files stop being opened at a certain point

Tags: python

I've written the following program in Python:

```
import re
import os
import string

folder = 'C:\Users\Jodie\Documents\Uni\Final Year Project\All Data'

folderlisting = os.listdir(folder)
for eachfolder in folderlisting:
    print eachfolder
    if os.path.isdir(folder + '\\' + eachfolder):
        filelisting = os.listdir('C:\Users\Jodie\Documents\Uni\Final Year Project\All Data\\' + eachfolder)
        print filelisting

        for eachfile in filelisting:
            if re.search('.genbank.txt$', eachfile):
                genbankfile = open(eachfile, 'r')
                print genbankfile

            if re.search('.alleles.txt$', eachfile):
                allelesfile = open(eachfile, 'r')
                print allelesfile
```

It looks through a lot of folders, and prints the following:

1. The name of each folder, without the path
2. A list of all files in each folder
3. Two specific files in each folder (Any files containing ".genbank.txt" and ".alleles.txt").

The code works until it reaches a certain directory, and then fails with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jodie\Documents\Uni\Final Year Project\Altering Frequency Practice\Change_freq_data.py", line 16, in <module>
    genbankfile = open(eachfile, 'r')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ABP1.genbank.txt'
```

The problem is:

1. That file most definitely exists, since the program lists it before it tries to open the file.
2. Even if I take that directory out of the original group of directories, the program throws up the same error for the next folder it iterates to. And the next, if that one is removed. And so on.

This makes me think that it's not the folder or any files in it, but some limitation of Python? I have no idea. It has stumped me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Backslashes are escape characters.  Either use raw strings like `r'C:\foo\bar'` or escape your backslashes like `'C:\\foo\\bar'`.  Secondly, use [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to join paths instead of hard-coding the directory separator.

Comment: Consider using [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk), if you need to check subdirectories as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should use os.walk() http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk

Also, you need to read the contents of the file, you don't want to print the file object.  And you need to close the file when you're done or use a context manager to close it for you.

would look something like:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
    for file_name in files:
        if re.search('.genbank.txt$', file_name) or \
            re.search('.alleles.txt$', file_name):
            with open(os.path.join(root, f), 'r') as f:
                print f.read()
```

Keep in mind this is not 'exactly' what you're doing, this will walk the entire tree, you may just want to walk a single level like you are already doing.